# Can I use the IP of an internal private NTP service instead pool.ntp.org spublic service with ntpdate?

Tags: linux, networking, time, ntp, ntpdate

I am not so into Linux and I have the following problem syncronzing two Linux machine using **ntpdate**.

I know that I can do it running this command:

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

that creats the **timesync.sh** script using the time provided by the **pool.ntp.org** online service.

Now for some organization policies I can't access to this service but we have an internal private NTP service. They provided me the IP address of this service.

So can I use the IP address of this internal private NTP service instead pool.ntp.org public service?

Can I do something like:

```
ntpdate IP_ADDRESS_OF_INTERNAL_PRIVATE_NTP_SERVICE?
```

Is it ok or am I missing something?

Comment: That seems quite feasible. Why not try it out now and post the result here?

Comment: I have an internal ntp service running on my firewall. All devices that need accurate time ask the firewall from the inside, while the firewall itself reaches out to the internet for ntp updates.